# UIScrollview images infinite scroll (image load) issue ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am trying to display images on `UIScrollView`, all these images are being displayed horizontally, However, the problem I'm getting a flicker in loading images on scroll.

I tried to use this code and modified UILabel to UIImageview and called async image downloading on scroll in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` - [Image Scroll Circular](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html) , one with 3 pages only. It works well with 'text label' example but when I asynchornously load images (cached as well), then there is a flicker
on scroll.

Suppose, if I scroll from page 0 to page 1 then page 0 flickers for a bit and then one can see page 1 again.

Any idea how to get rid of this issue?

Comment: try image view change image with slide effect

Comment: Sorry, image change with slide effect?

Comment: Take a view add image over it and change it with slide animation

Comment: Doing everything except the slide thingy. It eventually will double flicker it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add image using current main queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
});
```

Comment: I am already doing it via gcd and adding it on main thread. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My .m class you need a view and on that view an imageViewSlider(uiimageview) is added. combine it with activity indicator and detached fetch of image see if it works. This implements slide without scroll view

```
#import "ImageSliderView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#define kAnimationKey @"animationKey"
@interface ImageSliderView ()

@end

@implementation ImageSliderView
@synthesize imageData;
@synthesize imageViewSlider;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Set GestureRecoginzer..
    //******************************************************Swipe recognisers**************************
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightRecognizer=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandle:)];

    rightRecognizer.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

    [rightRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];

    [rightRecognizer release];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandle:)];

    leftRecognizer.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

    [leftRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];

    [leftRecognizer release];

    //******************************************************
    currentPage=0;
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setImageData:nil];
    [self setImageViewSlider:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
-(void)dealloc
{
    [imageData release];
    [imageViewSlider release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}




#pragma mark ---swipe
-(void)swipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)guestureRecognizer
{
    if(guestureRecognizer.direction==UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
    {

         [self nextButtonAndSlideForwad];

    }
    if(guestureRecognizer.direction==UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
    {
                [self prevButtonAndSlideBack];
    }

}



-(void)nextButtonAndSlideForwad
{


    self.imageViewSlider.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
            [self slideForward];



}

-(void)prevButtonAndSlideBack
{
    self.imageViewSlider.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    [self slideBackward];
}

-(void)slideForward
{
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
    [animation setDuration:0.4f];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [self.view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:0 withSubviewAtIndex:1]; 
    [[self.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:kAnimationKey];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.55];
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}

-(void)slideBackward
{

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
    [animation setDuration:0.4f];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [self.view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:1 withSubviewAtIndex:0]; 
    [[self.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:kAnimationKey];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.55];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

@end
```